# Set node request header based on encoded formData value

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, http-headers, npm-request

I'm attempting to send an HTTP POST, using the `request` npm package, to an API that requires a special header, consisting of a base64 encoded MD5 hash of the request body's string representation.

**Code to generate the MD5 hash:**

```
function md5(val) {
    val = val || '';
    return crypto.createHash('md5').update(val).digest('base64');
}
```

When there's no formData, for a GET or DELETE request, the value I'm supposed to use is an empty string, which works great. The API accepts the header and returns the requested data.

Unfortunately, when posting a file, using the `formData` option, the object is being encoded by the `request` module. So, when the server compares my MD5 hash with the body that's received on their end, it doesn't match and throws an error.

**Simplified request of what I need:**

```
var formData = {
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    profileImage: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test_image.jpg')
};

var reqOptions = {
    url: 'https://example.com/user/1234/profile-image',
    method: 'POST,
    json: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-MD5': md5(formData)
    },
    formData: formData
}

request(reqOptions, function(err, response, body) {
    //process the response...
});
```

The example above will throw an error, because the formData variable is an object and the `crypto` module is expecting a string. I started to manually write code to convert the formData object to a string, but it seems a little ridiculous to rewrite all of the logic that encodes all of the form values when it's already being done by the `request` module.

I'm looking for a reliable way to get the **exact** encoded form contents, after they've been processed by the `request` module, but before the request is actually sent, so I can build the hash value and add the header.

Comment: Have you tried encoding that as a ``Buffer`` and sending a  buffer with ``request``? This way you'll be able to actually extract the request body as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this manually with something like:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var FormData = require('form-data');

var form = new FormData();
form.append('left', 0);
form.append('top', 0);
form.append('width', 0);
form.append('height', 0);
form.append('profileImage', fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test_image.jpg'));

var rawChunks = [];
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
form.on('data', function(chunk) {
  rawChunks.push(chunk);
  hash.update(chunk);
}).on('end', function() {
  var headers = form.getHeaders();
  headers['Content-MD5'] = hash.digest('base64');
  var req = request({
    url: 'https://example.com/user/1234/profile-image',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
  }, function(err, res, body) {
    // Do something with response
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < rawChunks.length; ++i)
    req.write(rawChunks[i]);
  req.end();
});
```

Another possible alternative may be to use chunked encoding and pass `Content-MD5` as an HTTP trailer header (a header that appears after the body). This would allow you to prevent buffering the generated form data in memory (and possibly even buffering the file field in memory if you decide to change `fs.readFileSync()` to `fs.createReadStream()`). However it will all depend on whether or not the destination server supports trailer headers (whether parsing them or actually doing something with them).

Answer (score 0):

`request` uses the `form-data` npm package to encode form submissions. The object is accessible via `request.form()`. You should be able to take it and pipe it into an md5 hash instance:

```
var formData = r.form();
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
hash.setEncoding('hex');
form.on('end', function() {
    hash.end();
    console.log('hash is', hash.read());
    // submit request here
});
```

There may be an issue if you stream `form` into the md5 hash and then `request` tries to use the same stream again. In that case, require, instantiate, and populate `form-data` yourself to calculate the hash. Then create another instance of form-data and pass it to `request`.